# How to group columns and make links?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-desktop

Im trying to make something like this
[image]

but cant get how to group columns by actor and make the link to  exact movie.
Thats what I have now:

[image]

Some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to make a diagram that is similar to a Sankey (but simplest as the ticks of the lines are always the same).

The best way for you is to read about Sankey in Tableau on these tutorial

- [Chart Templates Part 1: Sankeys](https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2018/04/sankey-template.html)
- [How to Make Sankey Diagram in Tableau](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-sankey-diagram-in-tableau-f5f8730e5962)

then look at [these examples on Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/search/all/%23sankey) and finally, try to make a simplified version of the Sankey as you require.